# How to refresh the JWT token in nuxt.js?

Tags: django, vue.js, django-rest-framework, nuxtjs, nuxt-auth

I want to use JWT authentication in my nuxtjs app but it's not refreshing the token. For testing purposes, I set the access token expire time 5 seconds and refresh token for 30 minutes.

Access token expire after 5 seconds but the token is not refreshing after 5 second its logged-out

I'm using the **Django rest framework** and in nuxt I'm using **nuxt auth v5**

settings.py

```py
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework_simplejwt.authentication.JWTAuthentication',
    ),
}
SIMPLE_JWT = {
    'AUTH_HEADER_TYPES': ('JWT',),
    'ACCESS_TOKEN_LIFETIME': timedelta(seconds=5),
    'REFRESH_TOKEN_LIFETIME': timedelta(minutes=30),
}
```

nuxt.config.js

```js
auth: {
    localStorage: false,
    strategies: {
      local: {
        scheme: 'refresh',
        
        token: {
          property: 'access',
          type: 'JWT',
          required: true
        },
        refreshToken: {
          property: 'refresh',
  
          
        },
        user: {
          property: false,
          autoFetch: true
        },
        endpoints: {
          login: { url: '/jwt/create/', method: 'post',},
          refresh: { url: '/jwt/refresh/', method: 'post',},
          user: {url: '/users/me/', method: 'get' },
          logout: false
         
        },
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I'm little new in JWT and nuxt. Correct me if I'm wrong.

My main goal is just to refresh the token automatically when access toke is expired.

Comment: Hi, did you tried this one: https://auth.nuxtjs.org/schemes/refresh#usage Try to make a button a call it on click, for testing purposes at first.

Comment: would be good to have a bit more detail. What do you get in the web inspector when refreshing, what is you urls.py config,...

Comment: Possibly, you're missing the `data: 'refresh'` in your refresh config in nuxt, since you're using simplejwt and it's the default key that is used: https://auth.nuxtjs.org/schemes/refresh/#refreshtoken

Comment: hey @jkoestinger, Yes it's work. Thanks :) and one more thing, how to keep the user logged in until the user logout by themself.